# svn:externals is set, but has no effect at root

Tags: svn, version-control

In one SVN directory, I have two `svn:externals` definitions set, at the root and in a subfolder:

```
aromanov@aromanov-desktop:~/workspaces/odp-server/ru.focusmedia.odp.server.driver.vkt7$ svn propget svn:externals .
doc svn+ssh://192.168.1.102/repos/libraries/java/vkt7/trunk/doc

aromanov@aromanov-desktop:~/workspaces/odp-server/ru.focusmedia.odp.server.driver.vkt7$ svn propget svn:externals external/src/main
java svn+ssh://192.168.1.102/repos/libraries/java/vkt7/trunk/src
```

Both are committed. But only `external/src/main/java` is shown as external in `svn status`:

```
aromanov@aromanov-desktop:~/workspaces/odp-server/ru.focusmedia.odp.server.driver.vkt7$ svn st
X       external/src/main/java
?       target
?       generated
?       bin
```

or updated with `svn update`:

```
aromanov@aromanov-desktop:~/workspaces/odp-server/ru.focusmedia.odp.server.driver.vkt7$ svn up
Updating '.':

Fetching external item into 'external/src/main/java':
External at revision 93.

At revision 615.
```

Why is `doc` external not working?

UPDATE: `svn info` output:

```
aromanov@aromanov-desktop:~/workspaces/odp-server/ru.focusmedia.odp.server.driver.vkt7$ svn info .
Path: .
Working Copy Root Path: /home/aromanov/workspaces/odp-server/ru.focusmedia.odp.server.driver.vkt7
URL: svn+ssh://192.168.1.102/repos/projects/odp/server/trunk/drivers/ru.focusmedia.odp.server.driver.vkt7
Repository Root: svn+ssh://192.168.1.102/repos/projects/odp/server
Repository UUID: 9563c6ab-c084-4a4b-8888-c82da4f59334
Revision: 621
Node Kind: directory
Schedule: normal
Depth: immediates
Last Changed Author: aromanov
Last Changed Rev: 618
Last Changed Date: 2012-06-25 11:43:44 +0400 (Пн., 25 июня 2012)
```

Comment: can you paste the output of "svn info -v " on topmost wc-folder?

Comment: @PeterParker I get `Subcommand 'info' doesn't accept option '-v [--verbose]'`. `svn info` output added.